# axios not overriding default content-type header to

Tags: reactjs, axios, create-react-app

In my CRA project, I have set the defaults of axios (in root `index.js` file)

```
axios.defaults.headers = {
    "Content-type": "application/json",
    "Accept": "application/hal+json"
};
```

Now somewhere in the project I want to send `Content-type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request but the axios is still making `application/json` request.

```
const data = new URLSearchParams()
data.append('existingPassword', existingPassword)
data.append('newPassword', newPassword)

axios.post("http://localhost:8085/api/password-reset", data, {headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}})
```

If I comment out the defaults, this request works fine. Also, if the use `Content-type : multipart/form-data` then also defaults get override.

axios version `0.20.0`
react version `16.13.1`

What could be the issue here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the default content-type header uses the key `Content-type` and the axios call is passed the key `Content-Type`, the headers are not merged. Rename the default content-type header key to `'Content-Type'`.

```
axios.defaults.headers = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  // ...
}
```

[image: Edit Axios config]

> Also, if the use `Content-type : multipart/form-data` then also defaults get override.

It worked since you used `Content-type` which is same as the key used in the default headers.

Comment: nice catch. Thanks